# How to call a Windows DLL from within Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows, dll

What is the easiest way to use a custom DLL from within Ruby ?

In Python I would use *ctypes*, just as described as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173926/740316). But now how should I do it in Ruby, preferably using native functionalities over third party libs ? Is there any way Ruby can be as simple as Python for manipulating a DLL ?

Thank you o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Ruby's [`FFI` module](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-ffi-library-calling-external-libraries-now-easier-1293.html).

Two examples to get you started:

1. [Calling a C function from a DLL that returns a pointer to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14182535/181638)
2. [Calling a Win32 function from within Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14182709/181638)

The older `DL` module seems to be [less used](http://wmeissner.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/more-on-ruby-ffi.html) and [not as easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/269645/181638).

Comment: @NNzz: Excellent!  No slight to matt, but if you think this is the correct answer ("easiest way to use a DLL from Ruby"), you can deselect the check mark, and then re-apply it. ;)  Happy DLL-ing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`dl` module in the standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/dl/rdoc/DL.html). It’s not brilliantly documented, but the example there should point you in the right direction.

Ruby used to have a `Win32API` module for use in Windows, but [that has been deprecated now](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_286/ext/dl/win32/lib/Win32API.rb#L3) so you should just use `dl` directly.